# Two PHP Recursive Nav Questions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am very nearly done with this navigation...  I have the following code which recursively generates my navigation which can be seen at this link: http://khill.mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate/arraytest2.php

It also successfully adds a class of "active" to any link whose label = the page title.  Heres my code so far, see my question at bottom.  I have tagged javascript and jquery, but I would prefer a PHP solution, though I am open to suggestions.  Please note the whole purpose of this nav is so that I can add/remove/edit nav elements by editing a single file via the array below.

**Set the $title of page:**

```
<?php $title = 'Home'; ?>
```

**The navigation array:**

```
<?php

$nav_array = array ('Home' => 'index.php',
                   'About' => array ( 'about.php', array (
                        'Michael' => array( 'michael.php', array (
                            'Blog' => 'blog.php',
                            'Portfolio' => 'portfolio.php')), 
                        'Aaron' => 'aaron.php' , 
                        'Kenny' => 'kenny.php', 
                        'David'=> 'david.php')),

                   'Services' => array ( 'services.php', array (
                        'Get Noticed' => 'getnoticed.php', 
                        'Hosting' => 'hosting.php')),

                   'Clients' => 'clients.php',
                   'Contact Us' => 'contact.php'
    );

    $base = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
?>
```

**The foreach:**

```
<?php

echo "<ul>";
foreach ($nav_array as $nav_title => $nav_data) {
  echo buildLinks($nav_title, $nav_data, $base, $title);
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

**The buildLinks function:**

```
<?php // Building the links

function buildLinks ($label_name, $file_name, $active_class, $title) {

  $theLink = '';

  $navigation_list = false;
  if (is_array($file_name)) {
    $navigation_list = $file_name[1];
    $file_name = $file_name[0];
  }


    // build the links with active class
  if ($label_name == $title) {
    $theLink = "<li><a class=\"active\" href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
  } else {
    $theLink = "<li><a href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
  }

    // recursively loop back through build links function
  if ($navigation_list) {
    $theLink .= "<ul>";
    foreach ($navigation_list as $nav_title => $nav_data) {
      $theLink .= buildLinks($nav_title, $nav_data, $active_class, $title);
    }
    $theLink .= "</ul>";
  }

  return $theLink; // print the nav
}
```

So, I have this navigation visually styles already but it is generated using non-recursive nasty code.  You can see the arrows I am about to reference at the following link though, so you understand what it is I am trying to achieve. http://khill.mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate/

Note the arrows that appear only on nav elements that have a sub-menu present...

This is done by adding `<span class='arrow'> +</span>` inside the `<A>` label.  So for example... (class="" may have the class active if nav_label = title is TRUE)

```
<a class="" href="about.php">About<span class='arrow'> +</span></a>
```

So I am trying to figure out how to add this functionality to what is being generated recursively...  I guess my biggest problem is that I'm not quite sure how to identify if a sub-nav is present, and if this is TRUE, then add that `<span>`

I would assume that I would expand off of my original IF statement within the buildLinks function using elseif.  So...

// build the links with active class

```
if ($label_name == $title) {
    $theLink = "<li><a class=\"active\" href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
  } elseif ([what goes here?]) { 
    $theLink = "<li><a href=\"$file_name\">$label_name<span class='arrow'> +</span></a></li>\n";
  } else {
    $theLink = "<li><a href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
  }
```

The question is [what goes here?] in the above elseif line.  Also, I realize I would need two elseifs.  One for "if active = true AND if sub_menu = true" then this... and one for "if sub_menu = ture" then this...

At that point the above becomes...

```
if ($label_name == $title) {
    $theLink = "<li><a class=\"active\" href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
  } elseif ($label_name == $title && [what goes here?]) { 
    $theLink = "<li><a class=\"active\" href=\"$file_name\">$label_name<span class='arrow'> +</span></a></li>\n";
  } elseif ([what goes here?]) { 
    $theLink = "<li><a href=\"$file_name\">$label_name<span class='arrow'> +</span></a></li>\n";
  } else {
    $theLink = "<li><a href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
  }
```

I am now at a complete loss as I had help generating this recursive nav, I understand how it works mostly, but I don't fully understand what is happening here:

```
$theLink = '';

  $navigation_list = false;
  if (is_array($file_name)) {
    $navigation_list = $file_name[1];
    $file_name = $file_name[0];
  }
```

And I suspect figuring this out requires something from the above ^

**So my question again... what do I need to put in the [what goes here?] bits of my code to make this work?**

My second question, is more for me to further research, and that is what ways can I feed the above array more dynamically, preferably without MySQL?

**Edit:**  I have looked at this some more and I am still stuck on this bit of code which I didn't make myself.

```
$navigation_list = false;
      if (is_array($file_name)) {
        $navigation_list = $file_name[1];
        $file_name = $file_name[0];
      }
```

I understand the is_array operator for the most part.  With the above, by saying `$file_name[1];`, is that saying `$file_name[TRUE]`?  And then for the line below 0 = FALSE?

I need help in understanding how to detect if an array is present in order to print a link that includes `<span class="arrow"> +</span>`

Comment: Have you considered using a database for this? Rather than reading from a file and having to edit the file.

Comment: I have considered it briefly, and its something I am willing and would like to explore in the future.  The short answer for now is that I do not have the time to teach myself about databases in order implement that.  It's also something that I can update to later on.  For now I have two sites that need this completed quickly, and the only functionality I am currently missing, is the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I already warned you ;-) ... it was dirty code. 
I'll answer your second question since it's my fault:

```
/* $file_name is a mixed parameter, denpending on when
 *  buildLinks() is called, it will be $file_name (as in your first element 
 *  for 'Home' or an array with another navigation menu (as in your second 
 *  element for 'About'
 */
function buildLinks ($label_name, $file_name, $active_class, $title) {
    $theLink = '';
    // if this is false, there will be no recursive call
    $navigation_list = false;
    if (is_array($file_name)) {
        /* $file_name is an array, as in 'About' */
        /* so we get the second element to build the navigation list */
        $navigation_list = $file_name[1];
        /* and then set $file_name to the real filename string, which 
         * in your data structure is the first element of the array. 
         * This is why I suggested reconsidering your data structure.
         */
        $file_name = $file_name[0];
    }

    // build the links with active class
    if ($label_name == $title) {
      $theLink = "<li><a class=\"active\" href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
    } else {
      $theLink = "<li><a href=\"$file_name\">$label_name</a></li>\n";
    }

    // since we assigned $navigation_list to an array, this is true 
    if ($navigation_list) {
        $theLink .= "<ul>";
        foreach ($navigation_list as $nav_title => $nav_data) {
           $theLink .= buildLinks($nav_title, $nav_data, $active_class, $title);
        }
        $theLink .= "</ul>";
    }

    return $theLink;
}
```

The fact that it is hard to read code is just enought reason to change the data structure.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I figured it out mostly, but wasn't entirely sure what was happening at the top.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

After much thought, the solution to my arrow problem hit me.  I just needed to set a variable for active and a variable for arrow and place them inside theLink where they should be.  Then move the if statement outside of that.  It's not fully dynamic, as I have to manually declare which labels have a sub menu in order to get the arrow class to print, but as there aren't many links that have a sub-menu present, this doesn't bug me that much for now.

Here's the code for the solution:

```
<?php // Building the links recursively

function buildLinks ($label_name, $file_name, $active_class, $title) {

  $theLink = '';  
  $navigation_list = false; 
    if (is_array($file_name)) {
        $navigation_list = $file_name[1];
        $file_name = $file_name[0];
    }

    if ($label_name == $title) { // print active if it is true
        $active = 'active';
    }

    if ($label_name == 'About') { // print arrow if it is true
        $arrow = '<span class=\"arrow\"> +</span>';
    } elseif ($label_name == 'Michael') {
        $arrow = '<span class=\"arrow\"> +</span>';
    } elseif ($label_name == 'Services') {
        $arrow = '<span class=\"arrow\"> +</span>';
    }


    $theLink = "<li><a class=\"$active\" href=\"$file_name\">$label_name $arrow</a></li>\n";


    // recursively loop back through build links function
  if ($navigation_list) {
    $theLink .= "<ul class=\"sub-nav\">";
    foreach ($navigation_list as $nav_title => $nav_data) {
      $theLink .= buildLinks($nav_title, $nav_data, $active_class, $title);
    }
    $theLink .= "</ul>";
  }

  return $theLink; // print the nav
}

?>
```